# How to access individual values used by ndimage.generic_filter (scipy module)

Tags: python-2.7, scipy

Following code uses 'generic_filter' method, from **ndimage** (**scipy** python module), to calculate means for a sub matrix of 3x3 elements; considering each matrix element as central element (and excluding it) and avoiding border effects.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage

a = np.reshape(np.arange(25),(5,5))
print a

matrix = np.array(a).astype(np.float)

mask = np.ones((3, 3))
mask[1, 1] = 0

result = ndimage.generic_filter(matrix, np.nanmean, footprint = mask, mode='constant', cval=np.NaN)

print result
```

Result is printed as follows:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14]
 [15 16 17 18 19]
 [20 21 22 23 24]]
[[  4.           4.           5.           6.           6.66666667]
 [  5.6          6.           7.           8.           8.4       ]
 [ 10.6         11.          12.          13.          13.4       ]
 [ 15.6         16.          17.          18.          18.4       ]
 [ 17.33333333  18.          19.          20.          20.        ]]
```

and it could be corroborated that it works as expected [first mean is (5+6+1)/3 = 4, second mean is (0+6+5+7+2)/5 = 4; and it so on].

My question is how can I access to individual values (sub matrix) used by **ndimage.generic_filter** to calculate each **np.nanmean**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ndimage.generic_filter` calls an function once for each sub-array. You specify the function as the second argument. So if you change `np.nanmean` to a custom function `func` (see below) then you can have access to the sub-arrays from within `func`.

To accumulate a list of sub-arrays, which could be accessed after the call to `ndimage.generic_filter`, you could pass a list to `func` as an extra argument, and append the subarrays to the list inside `func`. You can then access that list (and its contents) afterwards:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage

def func(x, subarrays):
    print(x)
    subarrays.append(x)
    return np.nanmean(x)

a = np.reshape(np.arange(25),(5,5))
matrix = np.array(a).astype(np.float)
mask = np.ones((3, 3))
mask[1, 1] = 0
subarrays = []
result = ndimage.generic_filter(matrix, func, footprint = mask, 
                                mode='constant', cval=np.NaN,
                                extra_arguments=(subarrays,))

print(result)
print(len(subarrays))
```

prints each subarray:

```
[ nan  nan  nan  nan   1.  nan   5.   6.]
[ nan  nan  nan   0.   2.   5.   6.   7.]
[ nan  nan  nan   1.   3.   6.   7.   8.]
[ nan  nan  nan   2.   4.   7.   8.   9.]
[ nan  nan  nan   3.  nan   8.   9.  nan]
[ nan   0.   1.  nan   6.  nan  10.  11.]
[  0.   1.   2.   5.   7.  10.  11.  12.]
[  1.   2.   3.   6.   8.  11.  12.  13.]
[  2.   3.   4.   7.   9.  12.  13.  14.]
[  3.   4.  nan   8.  nan  13.  14.  nan]
[ nan   5.   6.  nan  11.  nan  15.  16.]
[  5.   6.   7.  10.  12.  15.  16.  17.]
[  6.   7.   8.  11.  13.  16.  17.  18.]
[  7.   8.   9.  12.  14.  17.  18.  19.]
[  8.   9.  nan  13.  nan  18.  19.  nan]
[ nan  10.  11.  nan  16.  nan  20.  21.]
[ 10.  11.  12.  15.  17.  20.  21.  22.]
[ 11.  12.  13.  16.  18.  21.  22.  23.]
[ 12.  13.  14.  17.  19.  22.  23.  24.]
[ 13.  14.  nan  18.  nan  23.  24.  nan]
[ nan  15.  16.  nan  21.  nan  nan  nan]
[ 15.  16.  17.  20.  22.  nan  nan  nan]
[ 16.  17.  18.  21.  23.  nan  nan  nan]
[ 17.  18.  19.  22.  24.  nan  nan  nan]
[ 18.  19.  nan  23.  nan  nan  nan  nan]
```

and prints the final `result`:

```
[[  4.           4.           5.           6.           6.66666667]
 [  5.6          6.           7.           8.           8.4       ]
 [ 10.6         11.          12.          13.          13.4       ]
 [ 15.6         16.          17.          18.          18.4       ]
 [ 17.33333333  18.          19.          20.          20.        ]]
```

and the length of `subarrays`:

```
25
```

Comment: I could use individual values (x) outside **func** printing them to a disk text file. Is it possible to print them to a variable for using them in code directly? (or, do I have to ask another question?)

Comment: You could append them to a list. I've updated the code to show what I mean.